# ASP.NET One page failure hangs all web pages

Tags: c#, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET website (.Net 4, IIS 7, C#).  From time to time the database has a deadlock when a person requests a record update.  When that happens the whole website hangs, even pages that do not access the database.

My question is, is this normal behavior for ASP.NET apps? One page hangs and then the rest of the website hangs?  If not is there a setting in IIS that would prevent this or a way to code the app that would prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, is this normal behavior for ASP.NET apps? One page
>   hangs and then the rest of the website hangs?

Definitely not. What's likely happening is not that the website hangs because there's a deadlock in the database but rather because you have some sort of resource leakage (memory, exhausting the # of threads to serve requests, CPU, etc.) that's causing the application to become unresponsive. In fact, you may think that the database is the culprit of this but I am more inclined to think that your code is the issue. Usually when there's a deadlock in a database (at least on SQL Server) one of the queries involved in the deadlock is automatically killed.

Comment: +1. This really needs investigation where it deadlocks. Could also be other parts (Application.Lock, never unlocking etc.) but it is not "normal behavior". Attaching a debugger, reproing and finding where the threads are stuck would likely help. Smells - as you say rightly - like a deadlock SOMEWHERE.

Comment: I did find out the query that causes the deadlock and I am currently fixing it.  What worried me is that at somepoint with any web app you are going to have a problem with a query and it seemed odd that it would hang the whole site.